# How many subgroups of order $p$ ($p$ prime) does the group $G = \mathbb Z_{p^3} \; \times \;\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime. How many subgroups of order $p$  does the group $G = \mathbb Z_{p^3} \; \times \; \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ have?

First, I want to make sure that I am computing these subgroups correctly. Is it true that $\mathbb Z_{p^3}$ has $\frac{p^3-1}{p-1}$ subgroups of order $p$ and that
$\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ has $\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}$ subgroups of order $p$ ?

Here is another go at the proof:

$\langle p^2 \rangle$ and $\langle p \rangle$ both have index $p$ in $\mathbb Z_{p^3}$ and $ \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ respectively.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G.$ Then $H =(a,b),$ where $a \in \mathbb Z_{p^3}$ and $ b \in \mathbb Z_{p^2}.$ First suppose that $a = 0.$ Then $b$ has $p-1$ possible subgroups. If $a\neq 0,$ then $a$ has $p^2 -1$ and $b$ has $p$ possible subgroups. Thus to account for over counting there are $\frac{p-1 + p(p^2-1)}{p-1} = p^2 + p + 1$ possible subgroups of order $p.$

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic groups have a **unique** subgroup of each order.

Your last paragraphs misuses words a bit. First you say $H$ is a subgroup, then $H=(a,b)$, but this is isn't possible since $(a,b)$ is an element, not a subset. You mean $H=\langle(a,b)\rangle$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $(a,b)\in C_{p^3}\times C_{p^2}$? Next, you can't say $b$ has $p-1$ subgroups, because $b$ is an element of $C_{p^3}$, and elements don't have subsets. I am unable to follow your reasoning.

Anyway, consider this: how are the elements of order $p$ and the subgroups of order $p$ related to each other? Can you describe the relationship between the numbers of each with an equation?